# "Low quality answer" Flag was declined, however post was ultimately deleted

Tags: discussion, flags, low-quality-posts, declined-flags, disputed-flags

I flagged [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30207186/3989608) post as "Low Quality Answer" since it was lacking content as well as it had formatting issues. You could have a look at the [Revision History](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/30207186/revisions) to verify.

Looking at the revision history, it is evident that *neither the owner deleted the post, nor did any moderator*. The reviewers decided to delete the post.

My question is, don't you guys think the following message:

> declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it

is not appropriate in such cases? Since, it was the moderator who declined, however, the reviewers voted to delete the post. There could be a mechanism such that the declined flag should not be actually considered as declined finally. Because, the post was ultimately deleted as it was flagged. Although, a moderator though otherwise, however, there was a conflict between the action of the moderator and the reviewers.

I hope what I understood from the revision history and what I tried to explain in my question is correct.

**Edit**

I don't think this is a duplicate question. The question picked as duplicate addresses "*how the flag was declined*" and not "*why*". I mean, the answers to that questions just tells whatever happened, but it doesn't answer "why" the flag was declined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Flagging an answer as VLQ is saying that the answer is so completely an unrecoverably terrible as to merit immediate deletion as there is neither any value there, nor any *potential* for an answer that even reaches the *minimum bar* for what even is an answer.

That post by no means meets those qualifications.

Not formatting the code as code is certainly a problem, but it most certainly is *not* an unsovlable problem; it's not even a problem that requires the author to fix; you could fix it yourself in just a few seconds.  This is by no means a criteria for a post being VLQ.

As for it lacking in content, if you feel that the post is a low quality answer because it is too brief and lacking in information then *downvote it*.  It sure looks like a low quality answer, but it *is* an answer, and it's an answer that could absolutely be improved to a *good* answer by adding additional information, so it's not beyond salvation.

That an answer is a *bad answer* is a reason to downvote, and optionally comment, not to flag.

The flag was *correctly* declined by a moderator, and *incorrectly* deleted by reviewers who deleted an answer despite it not meriting deletion from review.

Comment: Which flag would you raise in such case?

Comment: @LalitKumarB None.  The post merits no flag.  If you think it's a bad answer, downvote it; that's the appropriate tool for that problem.

Comment: Then, per your suggestion, majority of the VLQ flags are simply useless.

Comment: @LalitKumarB Why is that?  When you use the flag *appropriately* to allow for deletion of content that actually merits deletion, it can be extraordinarily useful.  Are you asserting that the majority of flags are incorrect?  Personally, I know that it is a frequently mis-used flag, but I wouldn't say that the *majority* of flags are inappropriate; the *majority* are appropriate flags, even if it's not an overwhelming majority.

Comment: I undeleted the answer. Now there's no conflict and everyone is happy!

Comment: Seems like, 'A' thinks 'YES', while 'B' thinks 'NO', but both 'A' and 'B' are correct. 'C' is wrong! Because 'C' brought 'A' and 'B' together, and then...

Comment: @LalitKumarB I'm not seeing what's so confusing here.  You *incorrectly* flagged a bad answer as VLQ, a mod *correctly* declined the flag, some reviewers *correctly* marked the post as okay, but 5 of them *incorrectly* said it should be deleted, deleting the post when it shouldn't have been, and then mmyers *correctly* undeleted it.  All of this is consistent with the fact that that answer isn't VLQ, even if it's a bad answer that merits downvotes.  And the fact that this one answer isn't VLQ doesn't mean that no answers are ever VLQ, or that the flag isn't useful when used *correctly*.

Comment: @Servy, Ok, I need to digest it now. Thanks for your reply and time :-) +1

Comment: @mmyers Thanks to you too.

Comment: @Servy - Too easy for you to just say that. But, I spent sometime to search for similar question, and then I had to include it. Else, one of those questions would have been immediately marked as duplicate. Now, a different question is marked, still wrong. But, nobody cares. Do you think it is a duplicate? If you think yes, then fine. Else, would you mind to vote to reopen?

Comment: @Servy, I think you are right regarding the confusion. I have rolled back the edit to what you suggested. I now think it is a noise, since it is not much relevant for those who understand and want to answer. Thanks again!